# cannot generate system identifier for general entity "TableRow"

Tags: html, hyperlink, w3c-validation

When validating a web page with the W3C Validation Service, the following problems arose due to a link in my page:

[image]

It seems to have a problem with the following link, because I get 2 warnings as well.

```
<a href = "http://www.monroecc.edu/DAuditSheets.nsf/Web+By+Dept/239E88B38B89F0718525776D00540A39?OpenDocument&TableRow=3.2.0">MC02</a>
```

I've searched, but I don't know where or what to look at to start looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: It means the ampersand needs to be encoded (as noted in the validation message). Is this a generated page, or is this static content?

Comment: @TiesonT thanks, that worked fine. I removed the portion "?OpenDocument&TableRow=3.2.0" and it works.

Comment: Well, that removes the querystring from the URL. If the querystring is necessary, you just need to encode the ampersand. If your content is static, replace `&` with `&amp;`. If it's generated content, the framework you're using should have a urlencode function of some sort.

Comment: @TiesonT. It still works fine without it, but I will bookmark your suggestion for the future. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TiesonT.: Don’t you want to add this as an answer?

Comment: @unor If I could give more than a general answer, sure. I'd prefer to know how the OP is generating their content, but they seem to be happy with what they're doing at the moment, so...